# Set data dynamically inside Ul element using c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to add some data which will fetch from Database and set inside the UL,li element present inside the section using c# asp.net.I am explaining my code below.

> index.aspx:

```
<section class="widget-alt location">
    <div class="widget-icon"></div>
    <div class="widget-title">Location</div>
    <address> </address>
    <ul>
        <li><i class="fa fa-phone"></li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-at">@</i>/li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-skype"></i></li>
    </ul>
    <nav>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="fa fa-twitter"></a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="fa fa-youtube"></a>
    </nav>
</section>
```

here i need to add `address` inside address tag and fill up also 3 li elements.All data will fetch from database.As i am  new to `ASP.NET` please give me some idea or any example code how to make this.

Comment: you will need to do this with javascript, try an ajax call to get the data corresponding to your address and append it to your li elements

Comment: @MihaiTibrea: I see no reason why this data can't be added server side. It will be much simpler to do as well. Unless there is a need to do it client side (eg this data is populated based on user input) then its usually neater and better to do it serverside when you construct the page.

Comment: @Chris, that is what i understood, the user will type the address, then load the rest of the info :)

Comment: Ah. My reading is that all the data (address and the three li items) all come from the database. If your reading is right though then use it woudl need to be ajaxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in .aspx include a runat server control (panel for e.g.)

```
<asp:Panel ID= "addressHolder"  runat = "server">
</asp:Panel>
```

in codebehind, .cs, at the point where you want to add the address dynamically

```
LiteralControl lAddress = new LiteralControl();
lAddress.Text = "Line 1<br />Line 2<br />City and etc"; 
addressHolder.Controls.Add(lAddress);
```